# AdventureWorks practise questions - esp correlated subqueries

Tags: sql, adventureworks

I am trying to hone my TSQL skills. I have downloaded the AdventureWorks database, but I could do with some example questions, the kind I would be asked in a real world business. Does anyone know of a list of questions out there for this database?

I am particularly interested in correlated subqueries. I adapted a question that a book I have presented. But in answering it I figured I could just use a left join and filter on the NULLS - I didn't need to use a correlated subquery. So I didn't get to practise one, and I still don't know when I would use them, or how my brain process would work if I was presented with a question that required a correlated subquery as opposed to a join (if there is such a thing).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This not really a a question for this site, but as I was many times in your situation I will help you as I can.

Make a query where you select all the clients that have no orders. I think this is the obvious example where you will need to use a subquery.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realise about the type of question allowed on the site. Will bear in mind for future. I think the query you asked I've already experimented with, and I join the customers with the orders, then simply use WHERE to filter out the NULL orders, so that it only shows customers with orders left. In other words, I didn't need to use a subquery: 
`
SELECT *
FROM
    [User]
 LEFT OUTER JOIN [Orders]
     ON [Orders].[userid] = [user].[id]
WHERE
    OrderPlaced IS NULL
`

Comment: SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE User.ID not in ( SELECT UserID FROM Orders ) this is the query using  a subquery.